# git upload the files as root

Tags: git, github

I've created a new repository in GitHub.
Then, I make a commit and push in my terminal.

But all files I add to GitHub have as owner root.
However, in my terminal when I check files permissions with "ls -la" they have 755 for folder and 644 for files with 1000:1000.
Why the owner is root when I use that repository in other project?

Comment: Don't use root for development. root is for system administration.
Someone could prank you with a git hook that deletes your entire machine.

Answer (score 1):

Git will only record 755 or 644 as permission. 
See "[How Git Treats Changes in File Permissions.](https://medium.com/@tahteche/how-git-treats-changes-in-file-permissions-f71874ca239d)"

And the local file owner is *not* recorded, which means if it is root when you clone/use a repo, it only reflects the local account you are using when doing those operation: Git knows nothing about it.
So don't use the root account when cloning your repo.

Comment: I have the project as dependency on composer. So I use the next command to add the dependency to another project: 
composer require "core/core"
this is launched from a specific container (docker). that container execute all command as root. maybe the problem is this, no?

Comment: @AgustinCastro Yes: your image could have specied a different user (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) than the default root.